# What could change the fps when copying frames from mp4 file to mp4 without reencoding?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame-rate, libavcodec

I try to copy video from in.mp4 to out.mp4 without reincoding. I'm using the code example suggested by **pogorskiy** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290413/why-decoding-frames-from-avi-container-and-encode-them-to-h264-mp4-doesnt-work). The copy process success, but the video is played very fast. I checked the fps of both files with [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en). The fps of "in.mp4" is 25 fps and "out.mp4" it **533fps**. I don't understand what changing the fps to 533 if I construct `outStream` from `inStream`?

I hope I explained myself correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in PTS and DTS values. They must be set correctly.

The detailed answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565062/fps-porblem-when-saving-video-in-mp4-container#13587332)