# getting frame using ffmpeg in android

Tags: android, encoding, ffmpeg

I wanna get frames from .mp4(recored by phone camera) using ffmpeg in android.
did! comfile and ndk-build
my questions are

1. for getting frames from .mp4, what should i do ?
   encoding ? decoding ?
2. encoded mp4 video file, could not play file mp4 on mediaplayer.

help me plz....

enter code here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libavutil/common.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
#include "player.h"

void video_encode_example(const char *filename, int codec_id)
{
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int i, ret, x, y, got_output;
    FILE *f;
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket pkt;
    uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };

        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BASEBALL", "%s",filename);

    /* find the mpeg1 video encoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_H263);
    if (!codec) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BASEBALL", "Codec not found");
        exit(1);
    }

    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BASEBALL", "Could not allocate video codec context");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* put sample parameters */
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    c->width = 352;
    c->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    c->time_base= (AVRational){1,25};
    c->gop_size = 10; /* emit one intra frame every ten frames */
    c->max_bframes=1;
    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;


   // if(codec == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
      // av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);

    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BASEBALL", "Could not open codec");
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (f == NULL) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BASEBALL", "Could not open");
        exit(1);
    }

    frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    if (!frame) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BASEBALL", "Could not allocate video frame");
        exit(1);
    }
    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
    frame->width  = c->width;
    frame->height = c->height;

    /* the image can be allocated by any means and av_image_alloc() is
     * just the most convenient way if av_malloc() is to be used */
    ret = av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, c->width, c->height,
                         c->pix_fmt, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BASEBALL", "Could not allocate raw picture buffer");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* encode 1 second of video */
    for(i=0;i<250;i++) {
        av_init_packet(&pkt);
        pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
        pkt.size = 0;

        fflush(stdout);
        /* prepare a dummy image */
        /* Y */
        for(y=0;y<c->height;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<c->width;x++) {
                frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
            }
        }

        /* Cb and Cr */
        for(y=0;y<c->height/2;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<c->width/2;x++) {
                frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
            }
        }

        frame->pts = i;

        /* encode the image */
        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
        if (ret < 0) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BASEBALL", "Error encoding frame");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (got_output) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BASEBALL", "encode the image Write frame pktsize  %d", pkt.size);
            fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);
            av_free_packet(&pkt);
        }
    }

    /* get the delayed frames */
    for (got_output = 1; got_output; i++) {
        fflush(stdout);

        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, NULL, &got_output);
        if (ret < 0) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BASEBALL", "Error encoding frame");
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (got_output) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BASEBALL", "get the delayed frames Write frame pktsize  %d", pkt.size);
            fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);
            av_free_packet(&pkt);
        }
    }

    /* add sequence end code to have a real mpeg file */
    fwrite(endcode, 1, sizeof(endcode), f);
    fclose(f);

    avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
    av_freep(&frame->data[0]);
    avcodec_free_frame(&frame);
}
enter code here
```

Comment: You have got licensed package lib of ffmpeg ??

Comment: Nomi // what's mean licensed package lib of ffmpeg ?

Comment: I mean the version of ffmpeg i got is trial based, can u share with me the link to this lib.. how u compiled it?

Comment: Nomi // i followed this http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/ and using ffmpeg/doc/examples/decoding_encoding.c file I wanna encode mp4 to mp4(slow motion) help me plz

Comment: U built that in linux ?
u can see this blog .. i hope it will help u: http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html?m=1

Comment: Nomi // i built that in osX! thank you so much! Nomi! it's so!!! helpfull i really thank u!

Comment: It was nothing :) ... Glad that it helped u :)

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290413/why-decoding-frames-from-avi-container-and-encode-them-to-h264-mp4-doesnt-work/13291637#13291637

Comment: @Nomi FFmpeg is free and does not offer anything that is "trial based".

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  ok then plz share with me something for windows :)

Comment: Nomi// ffmpeg4android lib is not for free T_T if wanna upload app using ffmpeg4android, pay for license