# h264 stream muxing: duration of resulting file is shorter than recording time

Tags: h.264, muxer

I am muxing H264 stream from v4l device to avi container using the approach outlined in the following [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964142/raw-h264-frames-in-mpegts-container-using-libavcodec)

The resulting files are playable, but for (lets say) 30 second recording the resulting file is only 10 seconds length. In other words, once I press 'Start recording' button until I press 'Stop' recording it is 30 seconds that have elapsed but file is only 10 seconds length (as shown in Windows Media player). Muxing starts immediately once I pressed the 'Start recording' button.

Any ideas on how could I approach this problem?

Comment: Is the video tripple speed or is is cut but playing in normal speed?

Comment: The speed is normal, same as the H264 source - I would say video is cut.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the fps parameter:

```
AVStream *pst = avformat_new_stream(fc, 0);
  vi = pst->index;

  AVCodecContext *pcc = pst->codec;
  _M;
  avcodec_get_context_defaults3(pcc, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
  pcc->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

  pcc->codec_id = codec_id;
  pcc->bit_rate = br;
  pcc->width = w;
  pcc->height = h;
  pcc->time_base.num = 1;
  int fps = 30; // problem here
  pcc->time_base.den = fps;
```

As it turned out, H264 stream produces frames with 13 fps. Once I made fps = 13, file duration become aligned with the expected time.